# Apply formula directly to a cell's value in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a stylesheet to do my accounts and I would like to have column for my future revenues. But I want to put in this column my revenues before the taxes and that a formula immediately change this value to the revenue minus the taxes.

So if I put 1000 in a cell, I want it to immediatly change to (1000 * 0,76), I don't want to have an intermediate column to calculate and I can't find a way to put a formula in a cell AND to still being able to give it a value after.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

That would be a very bad idea. What would happen if you repeatedly edited that cell? You'd keep applying the multiplication. Excel cannot distinguish between an initial edit and a subsequent edit.

If you *really* wanted to do something like this, then you could look at handling the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer Bathsheba!;) 
Actually I never thought of a "definitive" change, but something that might work like a formula, so if change the content of my cell, it takes a new "variable" to do multiplication again. 
I wanted it to work exactly like a formula between 2 cells, but without having to create the intermediate one. A cell that might be able to use its own value as the variable to multiply.

Example:

http://pastebin.com/qxkwVVCq

And still having the possibility to give a value to A1 to use for the multiplication.